# How to extend @Service?

Tags: java, spring

Here is a sample class below:

```
@Service("testService")
public class TestService {
    public String something() {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

I want to extend the class and let the container know that it needs to pick up my extended class from now.

```
@Service("extendedTestService")
public class ExtendedTestServiceMock extends TestService { 
    @Override
    public String something() {
        return "xyz";
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class TestClass extends SpringTest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("extendedTestService")
    private ExtendedTestService testService;

    public void testMethod() {
        ......
    }

}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [TestService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: ExtendedTestServiceMock,testService 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:865) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: If you want to create object of ExtendedTestService class  then you can remove @Service("testService")  from TestService class

Comment: check out this example http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-limit-login-attempts-example/  see the CustomUserDetailsService.java class.

Comment: @Dharmesh, i cannot remove @Service("testService") from TestService class, it's is real code, the ExtendedTestService class only for test

Comment: Change @Service("testServiceExtended")  for ExtendedTestService class

Answer (score 4):

Try using interfaces.

```
public interface TestService {
    String something();
}
```

Implementations:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("testService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService { ... }


@Service
@Qualifier("testServiceMock")
public class TestServiceMockImpl implements TestService { ... }
```

And the test class:

```
public class TestClass extends SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("extendedTestService")
    private TestService testService;    

    ...

}
```

Comment: If TestServiceMockImpl wants to use TestServiceImpl implementation like super.xxx(), how can I handle situation like this

Answer (score 3):

One solution that would work in your case is the `@Primary` annotation.

Your `TestServiceMockImpl` would look like:

```
@Service("extendedTestService ")
@Primary
public class ExtendedTestServiceMock extends TestService { 

    @override
    public String something() {
        return "xyz";
    }
}
```

Check out [this](http://toomuchcoding.blogspot.gr/2013/12/springs-primary-annotation-in-action.html) for more details on `@Primary`

I however suggest that you don't follow the above solution (since this will get out of hand very quick if you start using @Primary everywhere), that you instead take a look at [Spring Profiles](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/)

There are a lot of way you could create your Spring configuration using profiles, but regardless of how you end up configuring the beans, the end result would be a more clean design.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition order if your service define on the xml file.

Otherwise, you could use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to do this, which is only registered in the test scenarios that you want this mocked.

```java
public class SystemTestBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory) throws BeansException {
       // put your custom code in here
    }

}
```

Or you can use `@DependsOn` to make sure the parent bean should be deploy firstly then your extend bean

```java
@Service("testService")
@DependsOn("testService")
public class ExtendedTestService extends TestService {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an identifier to help you decide which service to initialize, then you can use `ConditionlOnProperty` annotation

Ex:

```
@Service
@ConditionlOnProperty(value = "test.service.extension.enabled")
public class TestService {

}

@Service
@ConditionlOnProperty(value = "test.service.extension.enabled", havingValue = "false")
public class ExtendedTestServiceMock extends TestService {
}
```

If you want to use the extended test service, you can set the property `test.service.extension.enabled=true` in your `application.properties`