# How to extend @Service with spring,NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring

Here is a sample class below

```
@Service("testService")
public class TestService {

    public String something() {
        return "abc";
    }

}
```

I want to extend the class and let the container know that it needs to pick up my extended class from now.

```
@Service("extendedTestService")
public class ExtendedTestServiceMock extends TestService { 

    @override
    public String something() {
        return "xyz";
    }

}
```

Test class

```
public class TestClass extends SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("extendedTestService")
     private ExtendedTestServiceMock testService;

    public void testMethod(){
        ......
    }

}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [TestService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: ExtendedTestServiceMock,testService 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:865) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: remove the blank in `@Service("extendedTestService ")`

Comment: Ary you sure that this is the code where the error comes from? I would say there must be an other pleace. where you autowire `TestService`

Comment: Thanks Jens,  yes, my test case like this.

Comment: Try to change ´private ExtendedTestServiceMock testService;` To `private TestService testService;`

Comment: @Jens, it still throw the No qualifying bean of type exception

Comment: I think you are searching on the wrong place. You have an other class where you autowire the `TestService`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend @Service with spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959033/how-to-extend-service-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a bean of type ExtendedTestService.

You have only defined a bean of type ExtendedTestServiceMock.

Try this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("extendedTestService")
private TestService testService;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think it is a write error in question,

Answer (score 0):

The solution is use a @service anotation, you should inject the service like this:

`@Autowired
private TestService testService;`

And then you can use the methods of TestService